# How to check if an index is empty/null in a List in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I wanted to check if an `index` of an `array` is empty/null, and if it's, then I wanted to add a new item at that index otherwise replace the old item with the new item (I do not want to keep the old item in the array).

I tried the following code but that didn't work

```
    private var mSelectedImageFileUriList: ArrayList<Uri?>? = null
mSelectedImageFileUriList= ArrayList(5)

        if (mSelectedImageFileUriList?.get(1) ===null){
                            mSelectedImageFileUriList?.add(data.data!!)
                        }else{
                            mSelectedImageFileUriList?.set(1,data.data!!)
                        }
```

---

`mSelectedImageFileUriList?.add(data.data!!)` is the code I previously used and it worked without errors. Then I try with `mSelectedImageFileUriList?.set(0,data.data!!)`, the app crashes. I am checking if the position (index) is `null` because there are chances it's already occupied and if it's occupied then I do not want the old data in it, instead, I want to replace it with the new one (new one should be at the same position.

It's basically for creating an array of `uri`. When the user wants to change the image, that is when I want to check if, at that `index`, the user had already selected an image and if he has, then the old `uri` must be removed and the new one should be added in the same position in the `array`.

There are 5 images, the size of the `array` is limited to 5 (`mSelectedImageFileUriList= ArrayList(5)`). When a user adds 'image1' the `uri` is stored at 'index0', and when he adds 'image2' the `uri` is stored at 'index1'. After adding 'image2' ('index1'), the user wants to edit (change) the image he added for 'image1', if I use `mSelectedImageFileUriList?.add(data.data!!)` it doesn't remove the old one and the new `uri` is added at the bottom on the array but I want it to be at the same position, in this case, 'index0'. I hope it's clear.

I shall add the complete code if required.

`logcat`

```
        Process: com.trad, PID: 21555
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/76207 flg=0x1 (has extras) }} to activity {com.trad/com.trad.ui.activities.AddProductActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5506)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5547)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
     Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
        at java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:453)
        at com.trad.ui.activities.AddProductActivity.onActivityResult(AddProductActivity.kt:354)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8541)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5499)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5547) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130) 
2021-07-11 14:33:46.867 637-1917/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [Application Error: com.trad#0](id:27d00004287,api:0,p:-1,c:637) disconnect: not connected (req=1)
```

Comment: I think you don’t yet understand that there is no such thing as an “empty” element in Kotlin. An array/list/vector/string can be empty (that is: having a length of zero), but elements themselves can’t be “empty”.

Comment: I meant `null` (no item), Is it OK now?

Comment: Not all types can be null though - you can’t have a null int, for example.

Comment: Is your `mSelectedImageFileUriList` an array? If so, it seems to be misnamed.

Comment: @Dai Could you explain it? If you got my question, then what would be the answer?

Comment: `mSelectedImageFileUriList?.set(1,data.data!!)` alone should work, unless you're trying to do something different to what you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others already said, you don't have to check whether the value is null or not, because in both cases you can simply do:

```
list[index] = value
```

Of in your case:

```
mSelectedImageFileUriList?.set(1, data.data!!)
```

This code does exactly what you ask: replaces existing value or "add" (actually, also replaces) if it is null.

But I think your problem is really somewhere else. You created your list with:

```
mSelectedImageFileUriList= ArrayList(5)
```

You probably assumed that it creates a list of size 5, but it does not. It creates a list with `capacity` of 5, but it is still of 0 size. It does not create a list like this: `[null, null, null, null, null]`, but just: `[]`, so you can't set the value for e.g. index=2.

To create a list of size 5 with nulls inside, use this code:

```
mSelectedImageFileUriList = MutableList(5) { null }
```

You will need to change the type of `mSelectedImageFileUriList` from `ArrayList` to `MutableList`. This is actually the reason why it is discouraged to use specific implementation types for variable types.

Comment: I have added the `logcat` in the question. Can you go through after Edit in my question I have mentioned why I cannot just add and need to check before adding to the array.

Comment: Yes, you added your explanation, but it is incorrect, because you based it on wrong assumptions on how lists work. From your logcat I clearly see that you didn't create a list as I suggested to you in my answer, because it is of size 1 and with my code it would be of size 5.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check for `null`. Since you always want to update that index, you can just set it directly.

For example:

```
fun main() {
    val list = mutableListOf("zero","one",null)
    println(list)
    list[1] = "oneUpdated"
    list[2] = "two"
    println(list)
}
```

Output:

```
[zero, one, null]
[zero, oneUpdated, two]
```

Comment: Wrap the code in a `if (list != null) { }` if your `list` is nullable, and make sure you decide what to do when the list is null, too.

Comment: I have edited my question, could you check it?

Comment: After your update the above answer is still correct. You don't have to check whether it is null or not, because simple `list[index] = value` does exactly what you ask for.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared an `ArrayList<Uri?>` which means that in your `ArrayList` contains either a `Uri` type or a `null` type. A `null` type still takes up a spot in the list, and isn't considered an "empty" space.

```
    if (mSelectedImageFileUriList?.get(1) ===null){
                        mSelectedImageFileUriList?.add(data.data!!)
                    }else{
                        mSelectedImageFileUriList?.set(1,data.data!!)
                    }
```

With this in mind, your code snippet doesn't quite do what you say in the description. Your code here is saying if the element at index 1 is null, append `data` to end of the list e.g. if your list was `[URI1, null]`, then your list will become `[URI1, null, data]` after execution.

It seems that either way (`null` or old value) you are looking to replace the value at index 1, so you don't need to check if the value at index 1 is `null` and could just have a one line setter:

```
mSelectedImageFileUriList?.set(1,data.data!!)
```

Comment: I have edited my question, could you check it?

Answer (score 0):

Use either `.getOrNull()`:

```
    if (mSelectedImageFileUriList.getOrNull(1) === null){
        mSelectedImageFileUriList.add(data.data!!)
    } else {
        mSelectedImageFileUriList.set(1,data.data!!)
    }
```

Or you could use `.elementAtOrNull()`:

```
    if (mSelectedImageFileUriList.elementAtOrNull(1) === null){
        mSelectedImageFileUriList.add(data.data!!)
    } else {
        mSelectedImageFileUriList.set(1,data.data!!)
    }
```